# connecting the head to other nodes in a linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I've created this structure for a linked list.

```
struct Node
{
    string name;
    int id;
    double price;

    struct Node * next;
};

private:
    struct Node* head;  

...
```

I'm trying to get 'next' in the head of my list to point to the first node I'm creating and inserting, but I seem to only be making the head node the first node. Why can't I fill in the 'next' portion for the head?

I've tried

```
if (head == NULL)               
{
    head->next = newNode;             
}
```

which results in "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x28)"

and

```
if (head == NULL)               
{
    head = newNode;             
}
```

which makes the head the new node, 
as well as some other solutions but none of them seem to be working.

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Look carefully at that first function. *Think* about it. Then try `if(head!=NULL)...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is definitely wrong, because it tries to dereference a NULL-pointer -- which is a classic way to invoke undefined behavior and (probably) crash, as you saw:

```
if (head == NULL)               
{
   head->next = newNode;             
}
```

If your list is currently empty (which should be the case if `head` is NULL), your second attempt (below) is correct:

```
if (head == NULL)
{
    head = newNode;             
}
```

One potential gotcha to watch for is to make sure that you also set `newNode->next = NULL` in the above case, since in a list with just one item, it has no subsequent `Node` to point to, but if you leave its `next`-pointer uninitialized you will invoke undefined behavior (and probably crash) when later on you try to dereference that uninitialize pointer.

OTOH if there are "other nodes in the linked list" that you are trying to prepend a new head-node to, then `head` should already be non-NULL (it should be pointing to the first item in the current list), so you'll need to set `newNode->next = head;` so that your new node points to the previous-head of the list, and then set `head = newNode;` since you want your new node to become the head of the list.

All of this becomes a bit easier to think about if you draw out some simple examples on paper (using circles to represent `Nodes` and arrows to represent where their `next`-pointers are pointing to, if anywhere).  If you haven't done that, I recommend it.

Comment: Ok, so the issue is that next is uninitialized and I'll run into this same issue with newNode if I don't initialize next for it as well. If I have a list with 4 items, will the last item be pointing at null? What if I need to insert on the end? If I have to run through the list will I no longer be able to use while(node != NULL)?

Comment: Next pointer of the last node of the list should always be NULL - that’s how you know it’s the last Node in the list.   ‘while(node != NULL) { [...] node = node->next;}’ is fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Your second attempt is correct:**

```
if (head == NULL)               
{
    head = newNode;             
}
```

You need to set `head` to `newNode`. Here, you are saying "if there is no head, make newNode the head"

**Your wrong attempt:**

```
if (head == NULL)               
{
    head->next = newNode;             
}
```

Here you are saying "if there is no head, set newNode to the head's next node" which makes no sense because how can you access the next node, if you don't have a head?

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you.